# How many times the constructors are called?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, move-semantics

I am quite puzzled by the std::move stuff. Assume I have this
piece of code:

```
string foo() {
  string t = "xxxx";
  return t;
}

string s = foo();
```

How many times the string constructor is called? Is it 2 or 3?
Is the compiler going to use move for this line?

```
string s = foo();
```

If so, in the function I am not even returning rvalue reference, so how could the
compiler invoke the move constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the compiler. In this case, the standard requires that there will be at least one constructor call. Namely, the construction of `t`.

But the standard allows the possibility of two others: the move-construction of the value output of `foo` from `t`, and the move-construction of `s` from the value output of `foo`. Most decent compilers will forgo these constructors by constructing `t` directly in the memory for `s`. This optimization is made possible because the standard allows these constructors to not be called if the compiler chooses not to.

This is called copy/move "elision".

> If so, in the function I am not even returning rvalue reference, so how could the compiler invoke the move constructor?

You seem to be laboring under the misconception that `&&` means "move", and that if there's no `&&` somewhere, then movement can't happen. Or that move construction requires `move`, which also is not true.

C++ is specified in such a way that certain kinds of expressions in certain places are considered valid to move from. This means that the value or reference will attempt to bind to a `&&` parameter before binding to a `&` parameter. Temporaries, for example, will preferentially bind to a `&&` parameter before a `const&` one. That's why temporaries used to construct values of that type will be moved from.

If you have a function which returns a value of some type `T`, and a return expression is of the form `return x`, where `x` is a named variable of type `T` of automatic storage duration (ie: a function parameter or stack variable), then the standard requires that this return expression move construct the returned value from `x`.

The return value of `foo` is a temporary. The rules of C++ require that temporaries bind to `&&` parameters before `const&`. So you get move construction into `s`.

Comment: What if we assume the compiler doesn't do any optimization?

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld: Then it would be the one constructor I said would happen plus the two optional ones that I said were optional.

Comment: do I have to change the function definition for foo, to be able to move it? I am thinking of:    string&& foo() {...} Otherwise how could the compiler know? String is just an example, in reality I have my own obj...

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld NO. Don't ever return rvalue references. Rvalue references are references, and in C++ you were never allowed to return a reference to a local variable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794. Rvalue references are still references; they are not magical.